# From binary to xml serialization using boost

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost, binary

I'm currently working on several classes that used boost serialization with binary archive using :

```
my_archive & my_variable;
```

However I want to move to add the xml archive serialization support, while keeping backward compatibility. Boost enforce (of course) to use the nvp wrapper for this reason.

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to mix nvp() and direct binary serialization in the same serialize fonction (with managing versioning).

So here what my code looks like until now :

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // serialize base class information
    if (version == 4) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp( "var", mVariable );
    }
    else if (version == 3) {
        ar & mVariable;
    }
}
```

With

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(MyType, 4)
```

When calling the & operator with xml archive I get the template error on is_wrapper<>() because some of my serialization is not using nvp wrapper.

So here is my question, is there any work around that could allow me to regarding the version number (know at compile time) to adapt the serialize function to use xml/binary for version 4 and only binary for the previous one.

Comment: So far I know you can use simply the make_nvp way. The binary format does not care about the text inserted and should keep working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always add the NVP wrapper; it's *just* a metadata annotation and it isn't used for binary archives (or standard text archives, for that matter).

So you don't even need to change the versioning, for binary archives

```
ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x);
// or
ar & boost::serialization_make_nvp("foo", x);
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
ar & x;
```